# Angular firestore app queries with userId not working

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I have an angular 6 with firebase application
I have a Service with an observable (i later want multiple subscribers listening to this same observable)
and also a component that subscribes to this observable
what im trying to achieve is to get the auth object, get the userId (UID) from it and search the db for all documents with this id

the component is calling the observable at the ngOnInit hook but at the stage its still null so i get

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

the problem is that if i run the code to fill the observable inside the subscribe block (to get the auth data) that i dont get to see the data, if its outside of it (running sync using static UID) than it does get filled correctly and shows data
here is the code for the service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, DocumentChangeAction } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Expense } from '../model/Expense';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject, Subject, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../core/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExpenseService {

    private dbPath = '/expenses';

    expenseDetailEvent: EventEmitter<Expense> = new EventEmitter<Expense>();

    expensesRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Expense> = null;
    expenses$: Observable<Expense[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, auth: AuthService) {
        auth.user$.subscribe(
            user => {
                this.expensesRef = this.db.collection<Expense>(this.dbPath, ref =>
                    ref.where('clientId', '==', user.uid)
                );
                this.expenses$ = this.expensesRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
                    map(actions =>
                        actions.map(a => {
                            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Expense;
                            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                            return { id, ...data };
                        })
                    )
                );
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }

    createExpense(expense: Expense): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.expensesRef.add(expense));
    }

    updateExpense(expense: Expense): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.expensesRef.doc(expense.id).update(expense));
    }
}
```

and the component just does

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.expenseService.expenses$.subscribe(expenses => this.expenses = expenses);
    }
```

i noticed that all the examples on line, call this on the component, but i feel that the database call should be in a service in a similar way that its done with normal http api calls

UPDATE
if i initialize the service like this

```
expenses$: Observable<Expense[]> = of([]);
```

so of course the app doesnt crash, but i dont see any data
if i just pull the code outside and use static UID than it does... (of course user.uid is the same as the static string i pasted)

here is the updated code

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, auth: AuthService) {
    console.log('being here ,i see the data on screen using the static uid');
    this.expensesRef = this.db.collection<Expense>(this.dbPath, ref =>
        ref.where('clientId', '==', 'noYVScDtKfNB5aFqRkAJR7ghxio2')
    );
    this.expenses$ = this.expensesRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions =>
            actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Expense;
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            })
        )
    );
    auth.user$.subscribe(
        user => {
            console.log('if inside here than it will not show any data on screen');

        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Comment: did you try to use ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: I did, no effect,  the problem is that the observable is being initialized after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `expenses$` Observable will be defined only after the `auth.user$` has emitted something, because then is when it gets assigned.

**Solution 1**
You could try injecting `ExpenseService` service in the constructor of a higher level component, maybe even `AppComponent`, so that the `ExpenseService`'s constructor gets called and the `expenses$` Observable gets assigned (you just need to inject it, without any method call or property access). At this point by the time you load the component the Observable should be defined

**Solution 2**
Manually create the Observable `expenses$` using `of` and then subscribing to `this.expensesRef.snapshotChanges()` you can emit values back in `expenses$`

Something like:

```
...

expensesSubject = new Subject<Expense[]>();
expenses$: from(expensesSubject);

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, auth: AuthService) {
    auth.user$.subscribe(
        user => {
            this.expensesRef = this.db.collection<Expense>(this.dbPath, ref =>
                ref.where('clientId', '==', user.uid)
            );
            this.expensesRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
                map(actions =>
                    actions.map(a => {
                        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Expense;
                        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                        return { id, ...data };
                    })
                )
            ).subscribe((whatever) => {
              expensesSubject.next(whatever);
            })
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on solution 2

Comment: I edited the answer, typings might need to be checked but you get the idea. In the component keep everything as it is.

Comment: bravo, it worked but i didn't quite understand why before it wasn't working and if its necessary to use both (expenses$ and expensesSubject)

Comment: Not necessary but a good practice. Usually you want to keep `expensesSubject` marked as private to the service and then `expenses$` as public. This avoid components or other services being able to emit data in the stream.